# CLLocationManager changes in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios7, mapkit, cllocationmanager

in an app we are developing we are using GPS in the iPhone to monitor location changes of the user (when driving) and using them to calculate used energy, power, etc.
This has been working fairly exact up to iOS 7 but ever since these values are quite off and we are struggling to find the issue.

Has there been any changes to the way the CLLocationManager presents it's data (speed, location, etc) or something else that might cause this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I know that the `regionMonitoringAvailable` function is deprecated.

Comment: We are not using this function and it wouldn't have any effect over our calculations. 
It's really kind of strange. At first I thought speed m/s might have changed to something different but that wasn't it and I am not finding anything else that has changed.

Comment: Other than that I don't think that there might have been any other changes. If there were, they should've been mentioned on the release notes.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the list of deprecated methods here:

[Deprecated CLLocationManager Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html)

It doesn't seem to be many changes apart from the deprecation of `regionMonitoringAvailable`

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7 allows application to fetch location only when application is in foreground.
See if the api `allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:timeout:` can be of any help to you.